# Jmeter Report:-How to download response parallel like browser jmeter shows by adding all sub url responses

Tags: jmeter

**Jmeter Report**: How to download response parallel like browser?  Suppose i have 4 request in one transaction controller and i want to get response parallel for all request instead of sequentially.

In my transaction controller 4-5 http request are present and i want to download response of all request parallel instead of sequential.

In report all response are added and then showing but when we are using browser response are showing by subtracting the depended or complete responses.

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about "embedded resources" - images, scripts, styles, fonts, etc. - you should not be adding requests for them manually, instead you need to configure [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) Samplers to do this for you (or even better [HTTP Request Defaults](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/why-its-so-important-use-jmeters-http-request-defaults/)). The relevant settings live under "Advanced" tab:

[image]

If the nature of the requests is different, i.e. they're [AJAX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)) requests which are not supported by JMeter out of the box the easiest way of executing them at the same moment is placing them under the [Parallel Controller](https://github.com/Blazemeter/jmeter-bzm-plugins/blob/master/parallel/Parallel.md#parallel-controller). It is not a part of JMeter distribution bundle and can be installed using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/)

[image]